# My background image is not showing up in emulator but in browser it is coming

Tags: css, cordova, emulation

I am using phonegap to develop android app
but in emulator my background image is not showing up but in browser it is coming
plz help me out what mistake i had done in css

in css3:-

```
background: url('images/pw.png') top left no-repeat !important;
```

in image folder my image is present

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this..

```
background: url('images/pw.png') no-repeat top left !important;
```

Comment: How is your answer different from mine?

Answer (score 3):

Check the location of image folder. As of your code, `images` folder should be ***inside*** CSS folder. And the syntax is wrong in your css.

```
background: url('images/pw.png') no-repeat top left !important;

|-- CSS/
     |-- images/
          |-- pw.png
```

If images folder is **beside** CSS, then use

```
background: url('../images/pw.png') no-repeat top left !important;

|-- CSS/
|-- images/
       |-- pw.png
```

Comment: my css is in css folder and image is in images folder

Comment: I understand, where is the **images folder** , is it inside CSS or beside css, based on the scenario use the above. See the `../`

Comment: previous i used only single dot but after seeing ur answer when i used double dot then its working